# Create snowflakes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create the snowflake using jquery. Everything seems ok but i want to do alert option when you click particular flake then it should alert the message. But i implemented the click function that alert option is continuously triggering. I am not sure where i did mistake. I tried the preventDefault  still nothing happens.
http://jsfiddle.net/vicky081/4cZdu/12/

```
 function snowFalling(){

        // move the snow
        $('.snow').each(function(key, value){

            // check if the snow has reached the bottom of the screen
            if( parseInt($(this).css('top')) > windowHeight - 80 ) {

                // remove the snow from the HTML DOM structure
                $(this).remove();
            }       

            // set up a random speed
            var fallingSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

            // set up a random direction for the snow to move
            var movingDirection = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

            // get the snow's current top
            var currentTop = parseInt($(this).css('top'));      

            // get the snow's current top
            var currentLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left'));                

            // set the snow's new top
            $(this).css('top', currentTop + fallingSpeed ); 

            // check if the snow should move to left or move to right
            if( movingDirection === 0){

                // set the snow move to right
                $(this).css('left', currentLeft + fallingSpeed );   

            }else {

                // set the snow move to left
                $(this).css('left', currentLeft + -(fallingSpeed) );                

            }                   

        }); 
        jQuery(this).click(function() {
            alert('You Clicked');
        });

        // repeat the rollIt() function for each 200 microseconds
        window.setTimeout(snowFalling, 200);            

    }        

    // call the function when the document is loaded completely
    generateSnow();   
    snowFalling();

});
```

Now i want to alert particular click. How to prevent multi alert on click the snow flakes.
Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Yfz9X/

Comment: Five-pointed snowflakes just look wrong to me. We do have [Unicode snowflakes](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/4cZdu/14/) at our disposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want the alert to occur when snow is clicked, move the handler to the point where the snowflake is created, not when it us updated, as you currently have it.

```
$('<div />')
    .addClass('snow')
    .css('top', snowTop)
    .css('left', snowLeft)
    .css('position','absolute')
    .html('*')
    .click(function() {
        alert('You Clicked');
    })
);
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cZdu/13/)

Comment: Thanks for your Reply and Point out the right way. :) It works great

Answer (score 1):

You're binding a click handler every 200 ms on each snowflake element.

It looks like `generateSnow()` would be a good place to bind your click handler instead.

You could also use event delegation and bind on DOM ready:

```
$(document).on('click', '.snow', function() {
    alert('You clicked');
});
```

Comment: @DanielGimenez Binding the handlers in `generateSnow` **would** be binding them when they are created, and the event delegation version of `on()` doesn't require the elements to exist when binding. Only `document` would have to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `click` handler to outside your `snowFalling` function, after you generate your snowflakes:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTPyD/)

```
// this function is to alter the top of each snow, using the handy .each() jQuery method
function snowFalling(){

    // move the snow
    $('.snow').each(function(key, value){

        // check if the snow has reached the bottom of the screen
        if( parseInt($(this).css('top')) > windowHeight - 80 ) {

            // remove the snow from the HTML DOM structure
            $(this).remove();
        }       

        // set up a random speed
        var fallingSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

        // set up a random direction for the snow to move
        var movingDirection = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

        // get the snow's current top
        var currentTop = parseInt($(this).css('top'));      

        // get the snow's current top
        var currentLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left'));                

        // set the snow's new top
        $(this).css('top', currentTop + fallingSpeed ); 

        // check if the snow should move to left or move to right
        if( movingDirection === 0){

            // set the snow move to right
            $(this).css('left', currentLeft + fallingSpeed );   

        }else {

            // set the snow move to left
            $(this).css('left', currentLeft + -(fallingSpeed) );                

        }                   

    }); 

    // repeat the rollIt() function for each 200 microseconds
    window.setTimeout(snowFalling, 200);            

}        

// call the function when the document is loaded completely
generateSnow();  
snowFalling();

$('.snow').click(function() {
    alert('You Clicked');
});
```

Comment: This will not work.  When new `.snow` objects are added the handler will not be created.