# CSS property doesn't change using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm making NY card and trying to set all snowflakes in random place, but snowflakes position from left works, but top doesn't.

```js
var snowflakes = $("#snowflakes");
var snowflakesCount = snowflakes.data("count");
console.log(snowflakesCount);

for (var i = 0; i < snowflakesCount; i++) {
  var snowflake = $('<div class="snowflake"></div>').appendTo(snowflakes);
  var left = (Math.round(Math.random() * 80)) + "%";
  var top = (Math.round(Math.random() * 40) + 20) + "%";
  snowflake.css("top", top);
  snowflake.css("left", left);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #1a0d81;
}
.snowflake {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background: url("../image/snowflake.png");
  width: 32px;
  height: 33px;
  transition: 5s all linear;
}
#snowflakes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="snowflakes" data-count="10"></div>
```

`snowflake.css("top", top)` doesn't work. All i got is https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JgiE.jpg

Comment: Inspect `snowflake` div

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/2yrejfkr/ , are you sure there is nothing else interfering? - @PardeepDhingra, your code is working fine, you just have a 404 for the background image so none of your snowflakes are actually visible. If you do an Inspect Element, they are all randomly positioned, both `top` and `left`.

Comment: As mentioned below, your issue is that you're using `top` as a variable name, which is a reserved keyword in javascript, and refers to a window-relative top position. I'm assuming it works in my JSFiddle above because of relativity, whereas if you run it standalone, it will error. Refer to the answers below, and in the future, refrain from using reserved keywords as variable names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2007/06/03/javascript-variable-names-you-shouldn-t-use/

You shouldn't use `top` as a var

Comment: This is the answer, Glad people are quick to downvote. Rename the variable to xTop and it will magically start to work.

Comment: @epascarello While I agree that naming variables after reserved words is a no-no and leads to issues, any insight as to why this works fine in some cases? For example, if you copy the code over the JSFiddle, there's no issue: https://jsfiddle.net/2yrejfkr/ - Just curious!

Comment: @Santi If you run it as a snipplet it does in Chrome. I verified it errors with top and without. It is "window" in chrome. Try it, make an answer with a snipplet.

Comment: @epascarello I assume it's an issue regarding relativity in which the snippet was run, being that JSFiddle is run in a frame and not a standalone window.

Comment: Your code in jsfiddle is turned into a callback for window.onload. If you're in a function, you can redefine top. This has nothing to with iframes:

`function foo(){
    var top = 43;
    console.log(top);
}` works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working snippet.  The other answer includes details as to why.

---

The snippet was giving an error against `var top =`

Changed the var name and it works fine:

```js
var snowflakes = $("#snowflakes");
var snowflakesCount = snowflakes.data("count");
console.log(snowflakesCount);

for (var i = 0; i < snowflakesCount; i++) {
  var snowflake = $('<div class="snowflake">*</div>').appendTo(snowflakes);
  var left = (Math.round(Math.random() * 80)) + "%";
  var topxx =  (Math.round(Math.random() * 40)) + "%";
  //console.log(topxx);
  snowflake.css("left", left);
  snowflake.css("top", topxx);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #1a0d81;
}
.snowflake {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 33px;
  transition: 5s all linear;
  color:white;
}
#snowflakes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="snowflakes" data-count="10"></div>
```

Comment: Time ago i receveid down votes because I sayd same thing of an other guy, but with a working example.

Comment: @Laurianti Please be a bit more wary when commenting. You've commented three separate times on different answers to this question, and a case could easily be made that not a single one provided any value or thoughtful discussion points - One of them simply said "This is the right answer", another was just a link that was already provided in the answer that the comment was left on, and this one, which essentially just says that you also came up with this same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code that was discussed here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119420/create-snowflakes-in-jquery).
Might not resolve your issues with this but will get you where you want: [jfiddle][2.]
Another option is a [JQuery-snowfall](https://github.com/loktar00/JQuery-Snowfall).
And a working example of this plugin [SnowFall](http://loktar00.github.io/JQuery-Snowfall/).

Good luck